# How to convert an empty array to an empty JSON object with sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm creating a service with sequelize and the response of some values is an empty array. I need to convert those empty arrays to a JSON object.

Is there any way to convert an empty array to an empty JSON object with sequelize?

I already tried

```
track = _.last(result.tracks[0].track) ? _.last(result.tracks[0].track) : {};
```

but it didn't work.

```
if (result.tracks && result.tracks[0] && result.tracks[0].track) {
    track = _.last(result.tracks[0].track) ?
         _.last(result.tracks[0].track) : {};

    track.status = result.tracks[0].status;
}
```

I expect the arrays to become `{}`.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a working answer, but not an explanation to the *falsy* empty array behaviour.

```
track = !_.last(result.tracks[0].track).length ? _.last(result.tracks[0].track) : {};
```

The number zero behaves *falsy*.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are in need of removing other properties to be empty.

```
if (result.tracks && result.tracks[0] && result.tracks[0].track) {
    track = _.last(result.tracks[0].track) ?
         _.last(result.tracks[0].track) : {};
    track.status = result.tracks[0].status;
}
```

But, please note that, here, you have already created a new item by running "track=...".
And it does not affect the arrays in original object "result.tracks[0].track".
So, I recommend you try this.

```
if (result.tracks && result.tracks[0] && result.tracks[0].track) {
    track = _.last(result.tracks[0].track) ?
         _.last(result.tracks[0].track) : {};
    track.status = result.tracks[0].status;
    result.tracks[0].track = track;
}
```